# how to handle csv with commas in string fields using mysqlimport

Tags: mysql, csv, mysqlimport

I have the following import:

mysqlimport --columns=column1,column2,etc --ignore-lines=1 --fields-terminated-by=, --verbose --local -u myuser -p mytable myfile.csv

I have a csv with the following:

> Beatguide,company,/organization/beatguide,beatguide.me,http://beatguide.me,DEU,,Berlin,Berlin,,"",operating,"Beatguide,
>   an electronic music events listing and discovery platform adding sound
>   to the experience of searching for shows and club
>   nights.",electronics|events|music,consumer
>   electronics|events|hardware|media and entertainment|music and
>   audio,0,,2013-01-01,,,,11-50,,,http://www.facebook.com/beatguide.me,,

You can see the short description has a comma, but is enclosed in quotes:

```
"Beatguide,
```

> an electronic music events listing and discovery platform adding sound
>   to the experience of searching for shows and club
>   nights."

Currently, the above mysqlimport statement splits this field.  **What parameter do I add to the mysqlimport statement to have it respect the quotes and insert the string with the comma instead of splitting it?**

Answer (score 3):

I added the following option:

```
--fields-optionally-enclosed-by='"'
```

This solved my problem.